# Oracle SQL Query for displaying values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as shown

```
Amount      Debit      Credit    Description
------      -----      ------    -----------
275.00      275.00               Payroll
500.00                 500.00    Payroll
288.00      288.00               Payroll
500.00      500.00               Payroll
600.00      600.00               Payroll
988.00                 988.00    Payroll
600.00                 600.00    Payroll
```

and I want to display two distinct numbers as shown below from the above mentioned table

```
Amount      Debit      Credit    Description
------      -----      ------    -----------
500.00                 500.00    Payroll
500.00      500.00               Payroll
```

and

```
Amount      Debit      Credit    Description
------      -----      ------    -----------
600.00      600.00               Payroll
600.00                 600.00    Payroll
```

Now, the question is what would be the Oracle SQL for the this Query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
select amount,debit,credit,Description 
from tablename 
where amount = 500 and amount = 600 
group by amount,debit,credit,description;
```

Answer (score 1):

try it using `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.Amount = b.Amount 
            GROUP   BY Amount
            HAVING  COUNT(AMOUNT) = 2 AND
                    COUNT(Debit) = 1 AND
                    COUNT(Credit) = 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c69f/5)

Comment: A++++. This is a perfect solution.

Comment: Based on the syntax you have written, there are no rows returned when I used that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
 Amount,
 Debit,
 Credit,
 Description
FROM
 YourTable
WHERE
 Amount IN (500.00, 600.00)
ORDER BY Amount
```

Comment: @user814064 `500` and `600` are what you would like to have isn't it?

Comment: @user814064 Okay, question doesn't have much description about that.

Comment: The data under amount, debit, credit, and description are changing values

Comment: SELECT invoice_num, amount, debit, credit, description FROM abc WHERE invoice_num = '&num';

Comment: The output of that table if I inputted in the invoice number (invoice_num) is (let us say) 1300104 is seen above...

Comment: what if i change the invoice number, let us say 1300555, the values will change but will have the same idea above.

Answer (score 0):

select * from table 
where amount in 
(select amount 
from table 
group by amount, description 
having sum(debit, credit) = 0
)

But its better to self join and group by with any ID column (I am sure that you will have in your original table) rather than amount. Because same amount may repeat with not equivalent debit or credit.